TypeOrm QueryBuilder add a new field if a relation was exist
this is my products entity:
@Entity()
export class Products {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    code: string;

    @Column({
        default: 0
    })
    quantity: number;

    @Column()
    price: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => Category, {
        cascade: true
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    category: Category;

    @OneToMany(() => Favorites, favorite => favorite.product)
    favorites: Favorites[];

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 1000
    })
    description: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 1000
    })
    attributes: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Images, img => img.product, {
        onDelete: 'SET NULL'
    })
    images: Images[]

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date

    @DeleteDateColumn()
    deletedAt: Date
}

and this is my favorite entity:
@Entity()
export class Favorites {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => Products)
    @JoinColumn()
    product: Products

    @ManyToOne(() => User)
    @JoinColumn()
    user: User

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date

    @DeleteDateColumn()
    deletedAt: Date
}

I want when I return all my products, add a new boolean key isFavorite and if a user has added this product to their favorite list it returns true and if was not returns false
this is a solution that AI gives to me but its not work:
this.productsRepository.createQueryBuilder('products')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('products.category', 'category', 'category.id = :id', { id })
            .leftJoin('products.favorites', 'favorites')
            .leftJoin('favorites.user', 'user', 'user.id = :userId', { userId: user?.id })
            .addSelect('CASE WHEN favorite.id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE null END', 'isFavorite')
            .getMany();

but in response, I cant find the isFavorite key!
NOTE:

a user may not login and send a request to get the products list, I don't want a condition that does not send the response when a user.id condition is undefined


What database are you using ?

MySQL*

@PabloSalazar MySQL

You can create function in the product entity to get the product is a favorite or not. For example
    public isFavorite(): Boolean {
        return Favorites.count({ where: {product: this.id} ) > 0;
    }

In your query, you need to add .select() before using .addSelect().
